# How to conceal WCF service address in Silverlight?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, security

We have silverlight application which consume WCF services. During penetration test we found few issues. One of the suggestion is to scramble / encrypt the WCF service address in silverlight side.

Is this a standard practice or does it have any value? Will the user be able to gain any information by knowing the WCF service location if the serivce is secured. Because the user can always decompile the silverlight xap and understand how we have encrypted WCF address.

Comment: There isn't really a point...you could just use Fiddler to find the address your Silverlight app is connecting to. If your service is secured correctly, your only real risk is a DOS attack I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding secrets in data that you give out (e.g. in client-side code) is a notoriously difficult problem. Basically, this is what DRM systems try to do, and none of them are hacker-proof. If you give someone both the secret and the code that retrieves that secret, someone will figure the secret out. And as JeffN825 pointed out, you could always use wire monitoring tools to figure out the address (a bit more difficult with HTTPS addresses, but still possible). So, I would not put much effort into hiding the address, it's just security-by-obscurity that only delays a would-be attacker. If the service requires user authentication, I would just focus on making that part secure. If you're trying to authenticate the app, not the user, it's a much more difficult problem that requires a whole separate discussion, but it's not solved by address hiding.